# How to add an array of datarows into an exisitng table inside my database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ms-access, datarow

I'm a newbie so don't laugh :#
I'm working with 2002-2003 Microsoft access database.
Now, I want to add an array of DataRow into an existing table that I've in my database. Is there a way to do that? because right now I'm just adding the rows with a foreach loop

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the foreach-loop actually is the best way to do it.

```
foreach(DataRow row in yourRowArray)
{
   dataTable.Add(row);
}
```

If you are using .Net Framework 3.5+ you can also use the DataRows CopyToDataTable() Method.
But you have to watch out because the Data in the DataTable is overwritten in this case.

```
DataTable table = yourDataTable;
DataRow[] yourRowArray = ...;
if(yourRowArray.Length > 0)
{
  table = yourRowArray.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

I would recommend using the foreach-loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe as array must be a saved file type i.e. excel or csv.  Be sure it is a clean grid of data without extraneous non aligned rows.

Then you can link to that file with Access as a table.  This is a manual step using the Access interface - in the ribbon it is the External area.  This link remains good - allowing you to replace the excel/csv with a new one as long as the location path and structure of the file do not change.

Then you create an Append query to write all the records from this table into the table in your Access database.

www.CahabaData.com